# bulkifying SOQL code

Tags: apex, soql

How to bulkifying this code and I'm trying to move the `eDetailList (SOQL)` from loop,

```
String myId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id'); 
 employeeSQL = [SELECT id,name,RecordType.Name FROM Employee__c WHERE Id = :myId];

  private List<employee_Detail__c> eDetailList;
  for(Employee__c e : employeeSQL ){
        empList.add(e);
      eDetailList = [select id,name,salary,address from employee_detail__c where id = e.id];
     //do more with eDetailList 
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

So what you are looking for is a classic [SOQL subquery](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/).

You would most likely do something similar to the following:

```
employeeWithDetailSOQL = [SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.Name, (SELECT Id, Name, Salary, Address FROM Employee_Details__r) WHERE Id = :myId]; //notice the Employee_Details__r this is the plural label of the detail object

for(Employee__c e : employeeWithDetailSOQL)
{
    for(Employee_Detail__c ed : e.Employee_Details__r)
    {
        //do some work here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues in the code above:

1. Assigning a variable to SOQL statement causes SOQL statement to run, so you'll actually get a list of Employee_c records back from this
   employeeSQL = [SELECT id,name,RecordType.Name FROM Employee__c WHERE Id = :myId];
2. Looks like you are inside a method, so you can't / don't need to put "private" access modifier in front of eDetailList. Since you declared the eDetailList variable inside the method, it'll only be available inside that method.
3. Querying by ID only returns 1 record, so you don't really need to run your query in a loop

If I understand correctly, you are trying to do the following:

```
String myId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id');

// Declare variables to hold query results    
Employee__c e; 
List<employee_Detail__c> eDetailList;

// Query by employee ID and get 1 record back
List<Employee__c> emps = [SELECT id,name,RecordType.Name FROM Employee__c WHERE Id = :myId];

// check if employee record is found
if (emps.size() > 0) {

  // employee record is found, so get it from the list
  e = emps.get(0);

  // query employee_detail__c by Employee Id
  eDetailList = [select id,name,salary,address from employee_detail__c where Employee_Id__c = e.id];

  //do more with eDetailList 
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: When you are posting code in an answer,  proper indentation and formatting will drive towards better readability. Select all the code and click `Ctrl+K`.  FYI, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks